# How to check if two NumPy arrays are approximately equal?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

[`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) (or [`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)) check if two arrays are approximately equal.  But they both raise an exception if the inputs are not of the same shape.  I wonder if there is a library function that can be used for checking 'approximate' equality of two arbitrary arrays?  I.e., something like

```
def allclose(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
    return x.shape == y.shape and np.allclose(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
```

In fact, for 'exact' equality [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) already does the job (by returning `False` on arrays of different size, instead of raising an exception).

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: @NilsWerner Nothing wrong with my solution (I presume).  But I want to know if such a functionality is already implemented in NumPy library, so that I don't re-invent the wheel every time I need such a check.

Comment: If it's only a question of shapes, can't you flatten the arrays before comparaison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a function, and for a particular reason: It allows broadcasting. That means you can compare two arrays of different shapes as long as they are broadcastable.

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]],)
b = np.array([1, 2])

np.isclose(a, b)          # row-wise comparison
# array([[ True,  True],
#        [ True,  True]])
np.isclose(a, b[:, None]) # column-wise comparison
# array([[ True, False],
#        [False,  True]])
```

So if your function allows broadcasting you want to know whether the two arrays were different, or just in an incompatible shape.

So if you want to retain broadcast-ability, I would suggest

```py
def allclose(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return np.allclose(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Good point about retaining broadcastability. I think your `try` block misses a `return` statement or something similar, though.  (Otherwise if `np.allclose` does not raise an exception the wrapper `allclose` will not return anything. Am I right?)

Comment: Ah right, fixed